# Assistance needed with basic Python program

Tags: python

I am trying to learn programming and was doing some exercises when I came upon this question involving loops. Here is the question:

> Create a program that gets the marks the user has for their classes this year (ask the user how many classes they are taking). Tell them how many classes they are failing, their best mark and their worst mark.

I don't know how to display the best mark and the worst mark. Here is what I got:

```
count = 0
total = 0

while True:
    mark = input("Enter a mark (0-100) <-1 to exit> ")
    if mark == -1:
        break
    elif mark < 50:
        count += 1
        total += mark

print "You failed",count,"class(es). "
```

Comment: **Hint:** You'll need two more variables: `best` and `worst`.

Comment: Or you can keep track of all marks (except -1) and take the `max` and `min` of the series.

Comment: Can you please explain where I would place the helper variables and how I would use them. I am trying to learn Python but I can't grasp the loops concept. Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's what I thought, but then I realized that he's on Python2.7, so `mark` becomes an int.

Answer (score 2):

Add two more helper variables: `worstmark` and `bestmark`.

Then in your loop, reason if the input is lower than current `worstmark` or higher than `bestmark`. Allocate the value accordingly.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that if you haven't done any classes then there's no "best" or "worst" mark.  So you might need to handle the first class specially.

Comment: Can you please explain where I would place the helper variables and how I would use them. I am trying to learn Python but I can't grasp the loops concept. Thanks!

Comment: It's wise to read some theory when you get stuck. Some Python 101 tutorials: http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers
Have fun!

Comment: Oh I found how to fix my program! Thanks for your help Sami, I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Good job. Have fun programming!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps:

```
# list of marks
marks = []

# get marks from user
while True:
    mark = input("Enter a mark (0-100) <-1 to exit> ")
    if mark < 0:
        break
    elif mark <= 100:
        marks.append(mark)

# count number of classes failing 
failing = len([f for f in marks if f<50])
best = max(marks)
worst = min(marks)

# check if a least one mark entered 
if (len(marks) > 0):
    print "The number of classes you are failing:",failing
    print "Your best class score:",best
    print "Your worst class score",worst
else:
    print "Your are not taking any classes!"
```

**Demo:**

```
$ python classes.py
Enter a mark (0-100) <-1 to exit> -1
Your are not taking any classes!

$ python classes.py
Enter a mark (0-100) <-1 to exit> 30
Enter a mark (0-100) <-1 to exit> 40
Enter a mark (0-100) <-1 to exit> 50
Enter a mark (0-100) <-1 to exit> 60
Enter a mark (0-100) <-1 to exit> 70
Enter a mark (0-100) <-1 to exit> 80
Enter a mark (0-100) <-1 to exit> -1
The number of classes you are failing: 2
Your best class score: 80
Your worst class score 30
```